# How to make a stacked bar bar chart year over year in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Following is a sample of my data:

```
   Year Category      `Percent/Count`
  <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>
1  2017 Non-Hispanic           0.580
2  2018 Non-Hispanic           0.55 
3  2019 Non-Hispanic           0.54 
4  2020 Non-Hispanic           0.54 
5  2017 Hispanic               0.42 
6  2018 Hispanic               0.45 
7  2019 Hispanic               0.46 
8  2020 Hispanic               0.46
```

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart in Tableau year over year. How can I do this?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a fresh empty Worksheet and follow these steps:

1. Select and drag 'Year' from Dimensions to your Columns Tab
2. Select and drag 'Number of Records' from Measures to Rows Tab
3. Select and drag 'Category' from Dimensions to Color Mark